# Flash under SSL

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, ssl

I have a difficulty to display Flash contents under SSL only by IE.
Is this simply IE's bug? Firefox can display the Flash.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the SSL cert into your keystore.  Double-click on the lock icon, then click on "Install Certificate".  Flash can be very finicky when it comes to SSL certs.  Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Thanks,though, this didn't work well. I'll try something more.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.sslshopper.com/article-flash-ssl-ie-wtf.html for a possible solution.  Flash is unable to load xml if the http header has either Pragma: no-cache or Cache-control: no-cache.